# Angular app not showing, blank screen not a known property errror

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to show another app inside a parent in Angular. It works fine in other components, like in this select-machine component:

```
<app-machine-detail *ngIf="machine" [machine]="machine" (selectedManipulationEvent)="onSelectedManipulation($event)" (selectProtectionEvent)="onSelectProtection($event)">
</app-machine-detail>

<app-ifa-button-bar-group>
    <app-ifa-button-bar-item [label]="'MISC.BACK'" (click)="navigateBack()">
    </app-ifa-button-bar-item>
</app-ifa-button-bar-group>
```

But when I try to use it in my component:

```
<ng-container>
  <app-machine-detail [machine]="completeMachine">
  </app-machine-detail>
  <app-ifa-button-bar-group>
    <app-ifa-button-bar-item [label]="'MISC.BACK'" (click)="navigateBack()">
    </app-ifa-button-bar-item>
  </app-ifa-button-bar-group>
</ng-container>
```

nothing happens. It shows a blank page with an error in the console:

Can't bind to 'label' since it isn't a known property of 'app-ifa-button-bar-item'.

1. If 'app-ifa-button-bar-item' is an Angular component and it has 'label' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-ifa-button-bar-item' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

   <app-ifa-button-bar-item [label]="'MISC.BACK'" (click)="navigateBack()">

The machine-detail component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-machine-detail',
  templateUrl: './machine-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./machine-detail.component.scss']
})
export class MachineDetailComponent {
  /** the complete machine */
  @Input() machine: CompleteMachine;
  /** event for selected manipulation */
  @Output() selectedManipulationEvent: EventEmitter<CompleteManipulation> = new EventEmitter<CompleteManipulation>();
  /** event for selected protection */
  @Output() selectProtectionEvent: EventEmitter<ProtectionAndOperationModes> = new EventEmitter<ProtectionAndOperationModes>();

  /**
   * The constructor of MachineDetailComponent
   */
  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Handles the selected manipulation event and passes is up to parent
   * @param manipulation the selected manipulation
   */
  onSelectedManipulation(manipulation: CompleteManipulation): void {
    this.selectedManipulationEvent.emit(manipulation);
  }

  /**
   * Handles the selected protection event and passes is up to parent
   * @param protection the selected protection
   */
  onSelectProtection(protection: ProtectionAndOperationModes): void {
    this.selectProtectionEvent.emit(protection);
  }
}
```

It has an Input "machine" so I don't know why the error happens.

core module (where the parent component is located):

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TakePhotoComponent,
    ConfirmationDialogComponent,
    ShareMachineComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    WebcamModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatMenuModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    TakePhotoComponent,
    ConfirmationDialogComponent,
    ShareMachineComponent
  ],
  providers: [NgxImageCompressService]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

ifa-button-bar-item:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ifa-button-bar-item',
  templateUrl: './ifa-button-bar-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ifa-button-bar-item.component.scss']
})
export class IfaButtonBarItemComponent implements OnChanges {
  private _buttonId: string;

  get buttonId(): string {
    return this._buttonId;
  }
  set buttonId(value: string) {
    this._buttonId = value;
  }

  /** label of button or name of translation value */
  @Input() label: string;
  /** color of button */
  @Input() color: string = "";
  /** disable button */
  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
  /** method to execute */
  @Output() click: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  /**
   * The constructor of IfaButtonBarItemComponent
   * @param buttonService the button service
   */
  constructor(
    private buttonService: IfaButtonBarService
  ) { }

  /**
   * Sends changes of disabled buttons to button service
   */
  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.buttonService.setDisabled(this.buttonId, this.disabled);
  }
```

ifa-buttton module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    IfaButtonBarItemComponent,
    IfaButtonBarComponent,
    IfaButtonBarGroupComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports: [
    IfaButtonBarComponent,
    IfaButtonBarGroupComponent,
    IfaButtonBarItemComponent
  ]
})
export class IfaButtonModule { }
```

mbsm module (where select-machine is located)

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MbSMComponent,
    MachineMenuComponent,
    NewMachineComponent,
    EditMachineComponent,
    EditOperationModeComponent,
    EditProtectionComponent,
    SelectMachineComponent,
    EditManipulationComponent,
    EditManipulationDetailsComponent,
    CreateManipulationDetailsComponent,
    ListFilterComponent,
    SelectManipulationComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MachineModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    mbSMViewRoutingModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    CoreModule,
    ProtectionModule,
    OperationModeModule,
    ManipulationModule,
    IfaButtonModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatMenuModule
  ]
})
export class MbSMModule { }
```

I tried adding the button-bar-module and the machine-module where both of the child components are located, but then it throws an infinite loop exception...

I am out of ideas on what the error can be.

Comment: What is `app-ifa-button-bar-item` and where does it come from?

Comment: Added it in the question

Comment: You didn't answer the second part of my question. Where does it come from? I don't see the import or declaration.

Comment: I imported it in every module besides my core module where the parent is located. But when I import it there it throws a "maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Comment: What module declares your `select-machine` component? This module must import the `IfaButtonModule`.

Comment: its the mbsm module and it already imports it.

Comment: @Pieterjan added the module, as you can see it imports the button module aswell.